# Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros, point-clouds, rviz

I'm trying to see a point cloud in Rviz but when I add the topic to de Displays i get an error (Rviz) and in the terminal where i opened Rviz I get the following message:

**Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty**

I'm working with OpenDR, specifically with the 3D object detection module.

**Warning in terminal:**

[image: Warning]

**Error in Rviz:**

[image: Error]

I'm trying to see other people's responses with the same issue, I have already tried it everything but this information is not valid for me.